# Did the makers of the Jurassic World have a contingency plan for the dinosaurs escaping?

Tags: jurassic-world-fallen-kingdom, the-lost-world-jurassic-park

In the movie *Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom*, in the end Maisie lets all the dinosaurs escape so they don't succumb to their death due to the hydrogen cyanide leak. Further, the dinosaurs are shown escaping to the rest of the world*.

So did the makers of Jurassic World have a contingency plan for such a situation where dinosaurs escape to the outside (noting that this had already happened once before in *The Lost World: Jurassic Park*).

*<sub>I'm aware of the 'lysine contingency' but this was shown to be useless at the end of the first novel</sub>

Comment: Does "shooting them" count?

Comment: @user25730, sure the bullets might harm the smaller ones but what about the bigger dinosaurs who have thick skins?

Comment: @shanu "shoot them more".

Answer (score 3):

This is addressed in the film and its [novelisation](https://jurassicpark.fandom.com/wiki/Jurassic_World:_Special_Edition_Junior_Novelization), as well as the viral marketing sites that were written alongside the film.

- **All the dinos are tagged (so they can see where they are at all times).**

> Vivian looked at him, and then spoke again. “Uh, cancel that. Getting
> new information now. Everything’s fine.” She looked at Masrani for an
> explanation. Why didn’t he want her to put out a park-wide alert? That
> beast was out there, running loose!
>
> “Let Asset Containment capture it quietly,” Masrani said. “The very
> existence of this park is predicated on our ability to handle
> incidents like this. It was an eventuality.”
>
> [image]

- **They have a dedicated world class security team, whose sole task on the island is to prevent the dinosaurs from escaping the island.**

> "We don’t have the capacity to take things for granted around here”, Vic says. “While some of our work is assisting the staff at Jurassic World, we also have a memorandum of understanding with the United Nations to monitor activity on Isla Nublar and its neighboring islands."
>
> Poachers have been known to risk their own lives working in the service of ruthless collectors. It has also been reported that some individuals have been responsible for mishandling captured specimens, with disturbing hospitalization cases on the Costa Rican mainland.
> "This area of the world is controlled by a multi-national coalition, and our Asset Containment teams spearhead keeping this region safe and protected. With the use of state-of-the-art equipment and communication technology provided through partnerships with various Masrani Global subsidiaries, we can do just that."
>
> A seasoned security contractor, Vic Hoskins was involved in overseeing the infamous flying reptile "cleanup" operation over Canada in 2001. Due to the professionalism his team displayed, he was hired personally by Simon Masrani to re-develop InGen’s Security Division, which helped oversee the protection of workers on Isla Nublar during Jurassic World’s construction.
>
> <sub><sup>[Jurassic World Viral Media Site - *Masrani International / Security Division*](http://www.masraniglobal.com/about/divisions/ingen/security/index.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: true, but in Jurrassic world(2015) one of the dinosaurs was able to remove its tracker and it literally  massacared the park's security team

Comment: @shanu - The crew certainly looked quite surprised about that (shortly before they got et)

Comment: yes, that particular dinosaur was comparatively 'smarter' but every dinosaur counts

Comment: @shanu - That's the whole point. Their hubris in underestimating the dinosaurs was (once again) their undoing. Technology can't beat life, uh, finding a way

Comment: hmm, nicely stated and very true,  +1

Answer (score 1):

Every few years, we seem to discover that some previously identified dinosaur species that were primarily terrestrial had a much greater capacity for aquatic locomotion than previously assumed. [An example would be the Spinosaurus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gx_BeIqT3OI) which, while able to, preferred not to walk on land due to their expected inability to balance on their hind legs for long periods of time. It's hard to tell how far they could swim (especially being amphibious), which is an important piece of information for this question since it would affect how they could spread to other neighbouring land masses; if majorly aquatic, with the ability to live (i.e. feed, rest) entirely in a body of water, they could have spread throughout all neighbouring parts of the ocean, dependent on the temperature ranges they could survive in.

Flying dinosaurs could have escaped easily from an island, though the effect of their escape would be limited by points of rest, food sources, and other landmasses nearby.

Totally terrestrial dinosaurs without the ability to traverse great distances of ocean would struggle to escape, so the only precautionary measures necessary would be prevention of smuggling them. However, in the case of smaller species of predatory dinosaur (e.g. Compsognathus, described by its associated wikipedia page as "the size of a turkey), much stricter measures would have to be in place to prevent them effectively becoming stowaways on tourist-transport vehicles, supply vehicles, and small watercraft operated by bad actors, which could enable potentially several specimens to reach other, larger landmasses and become invasive species.

It's definitely worth noting that because of the lack of information contained in fossils, eggs, faeces, and skin impressions, the writers and thus the fictional government bodies in all the Jurassic Park movies (incl. Jurassic World), the countermeasures could only have been as appropriate to the at-the-time understanding of the dinosaur species they were attempting to recreate.

If you factor out the writer-manufactured jeopardy that creates the drama in these films, a well prepared organisation for creating contingencies for these "resurrected" specimens could likely have covered all bases; air, land, and sea; smuggling, human error, coups by malicious foreign powers. They could have had emergency protocols in place both on the island and surrounding nations to neutralise any escaped specimens regardless of their mode of locomotion.

Of course, this is all quite speculative and you'd have to ask the writers themselves if they ever detailed the contingencies in their world-building process. It is also noted in the films' literature that the DNA used to recreate the extinct creatures is incomplete due to decay, and that they used modern reptilian DNA to fill in the gaps. How this would affect their ability to survive the modern world's atmosphere, utilise food sources (prey will have evolved a great deal since their natural reign), and otherwise survive is difficult to tell without the writers going into great detail about the biology of the specimens featured in the films.

Comment: Good point. I'm not sure it's an on-topic answer (fictional-world references from the writers/script etc.), but it's a great answer nonetheless. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance, enjoy the site.

Comment: If you could offer any evidence to back this up, it would improve it dramatically.